# Cloudformation template add Tags to Ec2 instance by passing parameter dynmaically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, aws-cloudformation

Need to pass tags from parameter in cloudformation template to EC2.
Like Tags: `[{"Key":"Environment","Value":"Test"},{"Key":"Application","Value":"Web"}].`
Tags will change they are not static.

Currently it throwing an error in cloudformation that Tags must be list not string.
When I change paramter to List. Its still not working.

```
pTags:
    Type: String
    Description: List of tags for the Ec2
    Default: ''
```

In Ec2 section added

```
Tags: !Ref pTags
```

Tried diff types for parameter pTags and also !Trasnsform incloudformation but it didn't worked. I was able to add tags by specifying them as static Key and Value.

Comment: Its not possible to do this way. You have to specify Key and Value separately.

Answer (score 0):

Tags is a list of objects.
Parameter of Type list is a list of strings or numbers.
So it is not going to work as is w/o transformation.

If you have fixed number of tags, but with variable values - just takes these tag values as different parameters:

```
Parameters:
  Environment:
   Default: "val1,val2"
   Type: CommaDelimitedList
  Application:
   Default: "app1,app2"
   Type: CommaDelimitedList

Resources:
   ...
   Tags:
    - Key: Environment
      Value: !Select [ 0, !Ref Environment ]
    - Key: Application
      Value: !Select [ 0, !Ref Application ]

   ...
   Tags:
    - Key: Environment
      Value: !Select [ 1, !Ref Environment ]
    - Key: Application
      Value: !Select [ 1, !Ref Application ]
```

P.S. You can parametrized tag keys (names) the same way.